# GTK sharp (re)presenting a clicked window (Ubuntu)

Tags: c#, mono, window, gtk#, bringtofront

For a project I need to make a popup which should be "re-useable" under Gtk-sharp (2.12).
I am developing under Ubuntu (14.04, LTS), Monodevelop (4.0.12)

When calling an update function it should refresh the information and show itself to the user. Refreshing isn't an issue. The issue I am having is when presenting the window to the user.

My idea is to use the window.Present() to show it to the user. When testing this, however, I am finding a strange behavior. Testing code is included at the bottom of this post.

Assume all examples start with a freshly started application

Scenario 1:

1. Start program
2. Click outside the window
3. Wait
4. Repeat steps 2 & 3.

Result: the window is shown, steps 2 and 3 can be repeated. No problem.

Scenario 2:

1. Start program
2. Click the "Hide" button
3. Wait
4. Window re-appears -> so far, so good
5. Click the "Hide" button
6. Click outside the window

Result: The icon appears but the window is not presented, sometimes the icon shakes.

Am I missing something here? Are more actions needed inside the body of TestPresent to Reset the Window?

The show is needed, in case the window is hidden.

```
    static Window win;
    public static void Main ()
    {
        Application.Init ();

        win = new Window ("Test");
        win.DeleteEvent += (o, args) => Application.Quit();
        win.Resize (200, 200);

        Button btnHide = new Button (new Label ("Hide"));
        btnHide.Clicked += (sender, e) => win.Hide ();

        win.Add (btnHide);

        GLib.Timeout.Add(5000, new GLib.TimeoutHandler(TestPresent));

        win.ShowAll ();

        Application.Run ();
    }

    private static bool TestPresent()
    {
        win.Show ();
        win.Present ();
        return true;
    }
```